# Extract maximum slope in different part of a plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm a starter in R and I need some help to extract maximum slope on a growth plot to apply a Gompertz growth law. I succeed to apply a linear regression and modelise my data with "pspline" but I have problem to extract the equation of this results. I need to find maximum plot in different point of the plot to calculate the growth rate.

```
day<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12)
cells<-c(100000;300000,400000,600000,900000,1200000,2000000,3000000,5000000,6000000)
d<-data.frame(day,cells)
#find maximum slope
#install.packages("pspline",dependencies = T)
library("pspline")
plot(d$day, d$cell, main = "data(d) & smoothing splines")
d.spl <- sm.spline(d$day, d$cells)
d.spl
lines(d.spl, col = "blue")
lines(sm.spline(d$day, d$cells, df=10), lty=2, col = "red")
```

Comment: You fit a smoother. There is no equation. Also, since your data doesn't exhibit any asymptote at all, you can't fit a Gompertz function.

Comment: i agree i made a mistake on my data it's actually more like : cells<-c(100000;300000,400000,600000,900000,1200000,2000000,3000000,3000000,3000000)